# Character replacement does not work correctly

Tags: xetex, expl3, characters, xstring, text-manipulation

I am replacing a character. It works fine if I give that character as input directly. But when that character is extracted from a string, and then fed in to command for the reassignment it does not work. Here is MWC with the problem. Please run XeTeX.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{stackengine}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}

\def\kdh#1{\topinset{\rule{4pt}{0.7pt}}{#1}{8pt}{1pt}} %dh
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_swar_string_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \swar_replace_with:f #1
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_swar_string_tl {#1}

    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_swar_string_tl {धं} {\kdh{ध}}


    \tl_use:N \l_swar_string_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand \swar { m }
{
    \swar_replace_with:f { #1 }
}   
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Correct output is \swar{धं}\\
Incorrect output  is \StrBehind{प धं}{ }[\this] \swar{\this}, it should be \swar{धं}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\StrBehind` is not expandable.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't define functions with signatures other than `n` and `N` (an sometimes `w` if you must). An `f` signature should only be generated by `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`. I think if you define `\swar_replace_with:n` instead and then do `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \swar_replace_with:n { f }` your code will work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry, edited the code.

Comment: you are now using brackets instead of braces.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Could you please elaborate? I am still learning expl3. I don't exactly understand these nomenclatures and how it works.

Comment: define `\cs_new_protected:Npn \swar_replace_with:n`, and then add  `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \swar_replace_with:n {f}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this gives the error ``You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode. ^^I\tl_use:N \l_swar_string_tl``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbDYb.png)</sup> base signatures for commands, `n` and `N`, both of which don't process the argument in any way.  You should only define functions whose signature contains `n` or `N`, which is the “base” function and takes the argument as it should be.

In your case, the argument seems to be some text, so the `n` type (a braced group of tokens) is the correct choice, so you should do:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \swar_replace_with:n #1
  { ... }
```

and then, if you want a version of `\swar_replace_with:n` that `f`-expands the argument, you should use:

```latex
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \swar_replace_with:n { f }
```

then you can use `\swar_replace_with:f`, which will correctly process the argument.

Though it seems to me that an `o` (to expand the argument once) or `x` (to expand exhaustively) variant might be better than `f`.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{stackengine}
% \setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}

\def\kdh#1{\topinset{\rule{4pt}{0.7pt}}{#1}{8pt}{1pt}} %dh
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_swar_string_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \swar_replace_with:n #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_swar_string_tl {#1}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_swar_string_tl {धं} {\kdh{X}} % ध
    \tl_use:N \l_swar_string_tl
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \swar_replace_with:n { f }

\NewDocumentCommand \swar { m }
  { \swar_replace_with:f {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Correct output is \swar{धं}\\
Incorrect output  is \StrBehind{प धं}{ }[\this]\swar{\this}, it should be \swar{धं}
\end{document}
```

and the output (with `X` instead of `ध` because I don't have the proper font):

> [image]

---

<sup>1</sup> 6, actually: `n` and `N`, which are “normal”; `p` which stands for “parameter specification”, like you see in `\cs_new:Npn`; `T` and `F`, which are the same as `n`, but they denote the true and false branches of conditionals; `D`, which stands for “Do not use”, and is used  to name TeX primitives; and `w`, which should be used when the command doesn't follow one of the above. For starters, I suggest reading [The `expl3` package and LaTeX3 programming](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly, I tried to read the documentation but I haven't gained much. Are there any other sources that teach latex3 programming from basics?

Comment: @Girish We (LaTeX Team) are aware that the current documentation on `expl3` is not the most beginner-friendly there is, and we plan on writing a beginner's manual (suggestions welcome). Speaking from my own experience with `expl3`: start by reading `expl3.pdf` (even if you don't understand some parts of it), and then move to `interface3.pdf` to see what functions the LaTeX3 kernel provides (both these files can be found at ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel), then go by using it. Any problem you find, you're welcome to ask here :-)

Comment: Thank you for the pointers I will go through it.